# Cowboy example can't be compiled

Tags: templates, erlang, cowboy

I try to make Cookie example from Cowboy examples, but I get next error:

`..................................................
Finished in 16.335 seconds
770 tests, 0 failures
 ERLC   cookie_app.erl cookie_sup.erl toppage_handler.erl
 DTL    toppage.dtl
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{merl,term,[<<237 bytes>>],[]},{erlydtl_beam_compiler,string_ast,2,[{file,"src/erlydtl_beam_compiler.erl"},{line,966}]},{lists,mapfoldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1352}]},{erlydtl_beam_compiler,body_ast,3,[{file,"src/erlydtl_beam_compiler.erl"},{line,685}]},{erlydtl_beam_compiler,compile_to_binary,3,[{file,"src/erlydtl_beam_compiler.erl"},{line,195}]},{erlydtl_compiler,compile,1,[{file,"src/erlydtl_compiler.erl"},{line,206}]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,657}]},{erl_eval,eval_lc1,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,683}]}]}}
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
make: * [ebin/cookie.app] Error 1`

Somebody faced with same trouble? What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used cowboy before. According to the error message, merl application doesn't included. try `rebar delete-deps
rebar clean
rebar get-deps`

Then compile cowboy again.

Comment: In example uses erlang.mk. You can see here https://github.com/extend/cowboy/tree/master/examples/cookie

Answer (score 0):

As supposed, the root of problem is in path to dependencies. I moved  `ebin` and `src` folders from `~/cowboy/examples/cookie/deps/erlydtl/deps/merl` to `/usr/local/lib/erlang/lib/merl` and then app is built successfully.